# Objective-C NSMutableArray: Problem with sorting objects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

I  currently have an object called Station defined as:

```
@interface RFStation : NSObject {

    NSString *stationID; 
    NSString *callsign; 
    NSString *logo; 
    NSString *frequency;
@end
```

I also have an NSMutableArray containing a list of 'Station' objects.
I need to have a method to sort these objects by the 'stationState' attribute.

I implemented this method:

```
NSComparisonResult compareCallSign(RFStation *firstStation, RFStation *secondStation, void *context) {
    if ([firstStation.stationState compare:secondStation.stationState]){
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }else{
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }

}
```

and call it using:

```
[stationList sortedArrayUsingFunction:compareState context:nil];
[self.tableView reloadData]
```

(the data is loaded into a UITableViewController)

Can someone please tell me why my NSMutableArray is not getting sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-sortedArrayUsingFunction:…` does not modify the array. It just copies the array, sort it, and return the new sorted one.

To sort the mutable array in-place, use the `-sortUsingFunction:context:` method.

```
[stationList sortUsingFunction:compareState context:nil];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

---

BTW,

1. The `-compare:` method already returns a NSComparisonResult. Your function should be implemented as

   ```
   NSComparisonResult compareCallSign(...) {
       return [firstStation.stationState compare:secondStation.stationState];
   }
   ```
2. you could just use an NSSortDescriptor.

   ```
   NSSortDescriptor* sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"stationState" 
                                                        ascending:YES];
   [stationList sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sd]];
   [self.tableView reloadData];
   ```

Comment: WOW!! Your second solution was fantastic.. Thank-you soo much. Now only if there was a way to give a +3 for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

well something obvious, you've named your sort method compareCallSign and you've passed compareState to sortedArrayUsingFunction